# How to read in data and assign marker to a layer based on variable in data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I am attempting to create a map with layers based on time periods. I would like to be able to link markers to a google spreadsheet so people can add markers if needed. However, I have been unsuccessful at getting the markers to populate in the layer they are assigned.

I have included a fiddle below but I think my issue is somewhere here:

```
var code = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L4L6ezp4Z38cfundpYUv1wEEkM-kDFClldq7kuZbEVw/edit?usp=sharing';


function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    for(var row in data){
        var marker = L.marker([
            data[row].lat,
            data[row].lng
        ])
        .addTo(data[row].groupfor);
    }
}   

function init() {
    Tabletop.init({
        key: code,
        callback: addPoints,
        simpleSheet: true
    })
}
init()
```

the markers are added to the map correctly when I use addTo(map); however, I would like to assign them to layers based on the variable groupfor in my data.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k30f4xbh/)

Currently, none of the markers populate in the map but I want them to be assigned to the correct layer in the map based on the variable I assign them in the data.

Comment: How is `data[row].groupfor` initialised? What type is it?

Comment: It is supposed to reference a string in my spreadsheet such as "AD500" that is the layer name it is supposed to be assigned to. That may be where I am going wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by changing .addTo(data[row].groupfor) to .addTo(window[data[row].groupfor]);

Don't know if this is the best way to do that but it worked for me.

Comment: `addTo` takes a map or layer group as its argument - it's hard to see how it would work passing it a string.

Comment: The layergroups were created before this and the variable in that row references the layergroup I want it to be in. So when window prints that variable in there it is adding the marker to the correct layergroup?